# How to pass values from two different Models to the View file via the Controller as a single return variable in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

I have an Appointment listing where I need to show the Appointment detail on one side and the Current status highlighted on the other side from the list of available Status's

I have 2 models,

1. Appointment Model for getting the appointment details
2. AppointmentStatus Model for getting the current status of the Appointment( Status is stored status table and AppointmentStatus table only have relation to the status table.)

This is my controller functions

```
public function details($id ,Request $request)
{
    $appointment = new Appointment;
    $appointmentStatus = new AppointmentStatus;
    $eventDetail = $appointment->getEventsDetails($id);
    $status = $appointmentStatus->getCurrentStatus($id);
    $data = $eventDetail->concat($status);
    return $data;

}
```

`$eventDetail` contains all details of the appointment and in `$status`, I got the current status of the appointment. Now I have doubts regarding How can I pass these 2 variables to a single view file where I need to print both.

**getCurrentStatus Function**

```
 public function getCurrentStatus($id)
{
    $status = DB::table("appointment_status_tbl")
        ->join("booking_status_tbl", function($join){
            $join->on("appointment_status_tbl.booking_status_id", "=", "booking_status_tbl.id");
        })
        ->select(
            "booking_status_tbl.booking_status",
            )
        ->where('appointment_status_tbl.appointment_id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
        return view('/detail',compact('status'));
}
```

**getEventDetails Function**

```
public function getEventsDetails($id){
    $getdata = DB::table("appointments_tbl")
        ->join("patients_tbl", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.patient_id", "=", "patients_tbl.id");
        })
        ->join("doctors_tbl", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.doctor_id", "=", "doctors_tbl.id");
        })
        ->join("payment_tbl", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.payment_id", "=", "payment_tbl.id");
        })
        ->join("treatment_category", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.treatment_category", "=", "treatment_category.id");
        })
        ->join("treatment_options", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.treatment_option", "=", "treatment_options.id");
        })
        ->select(
            "appointments_tbl.id",
            "appointments_tbl.start_time",
            "appointments_tbl.end_time",
            "patients_tbl.status",
            "patients_tbl.first_name",
            "patients_tbl.last_name",
            "appointments_tbl.patient_id",
            "patients_tbl.phone",
            "patients_tbl.email",
            "patients_tbl.address",
            "patients_tbl.city",
            "patients_tbl.dob",
            "patients_tbl.postal_code",
            "doctors_tbl.doctor_name",
            "treatment_category.category_name",
            "treatment_options.treatment_name",
            "payment_tbl.payment_status",
            "appointments_tbl.covid_19_symptoms"
        )
        ->where('appointments_tbl.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
        foreach ($getdata as $values) {
            $id = $values->id;
            $patientID = $values->patient_id;
            $start_date = $values->start_time;
            $upcoming = DB::table("appointments_tbl")
                ->join("treatment_options", function($join){
                    $join->on("appointments_tbl.treatment_option", "=", "treatment_options.id");
                })
                ->select(
                    "appointments_tbl.id",
                    "treatment_options.treatment_name",
                    "appointments_tbl.start_time",
                    )
                ->where('appointments_tbl.patient_id', '=', $patientID)
                ->where('start_time', '>', $start_date)
                ->get();

            $previous = DB::table("appointments_tbl")
                ->join("treatment_options", function($join){
                    $join->on("appointments_tbl.treatment_option", "=", "treatment_options.id");
                })
                ->select(
                    "appointments_tbl.id",
                    "treatment_options.treatment_name",
                    "appointments_tbl.start_time",
                    )
                ->where('appointments_tbl.patient_id', '=', $patientID)
                ->where('start_time', '<', $start_date)
                ->get();
        }
    
        return view('/detail',compact('getdata','upcoming','previous'));
}
```

I tried `concat()` but it returns the following error: [image]

Help Me please to solve the issues..

Thank you!

Comment: do the `getEventDetails` and `getCurrentStatus` functions return a view?

Comment: if I Wright `return getEventDetails;` event details will be successfully displaying and if I wright the second one, it will return successfully, But I need both

Comment: Normally you return the collection from your functions and you end the controller action by returning a view. in that case you can pass 2 variables to the view. you cannot return 2 views or concat 2 views

Comment: It is just one single view file, But I need to return 2 different data from different models via a single controller. I can pass either of them. But how to pass both?

Comment: can you share the 2 functions? the error says the `$eventDeal`variable contains a view object.

Comment: Please check the question part, I have updated the question with 2 functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239024/discussion-between-user12414491-and-gert-b).

Answer (score 1):

Your functions should only return the data:

```
return compact('getdata','upcoming','previous');
```

same for the other function, then merge the 2 arrays and return a view in the controller.

```
$data = array_merge($eventDetail, $status);
return view('detail', $data);
```

Check your view name, normally they don't start with a `/`